# Migration from a remote database PDOException

Tags: migrations, database

I'm setting up a database migration. For now, I'm using the ssh tunnel to access the remote databse.

Here is the configuration in the Migration class:

```
<?php
...
Database::addConnectionInfo('for_migration', 'default', array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'database',
  'username' => 'user',
  'password' => '****',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '1000',
  'prefix' => '',
));

// Conect to the remote $databases
$query = Database::getConnection('default', 'for_migration')
    ->select('Content', 'ct');

// Better descriptions for wineid and name; best_vintages is added in prepareRow()
$source_fields = array(
  'id' => t('article ID'),
  'contenido' => t('Contenido'),
);

// Create a MigrateSource object, which manages retrieving the input data.
// Tell the source class not to try to join the map table.
$this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query,
    $source_fields,
    NULL,
    array('map_joinable' => FALSE)
    );

$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationNode('article');

$this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
    array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'int',
                           'not null' => TRUE,
                           'description' => 'Article ID',
                           'alias' => 'id',
                          ),
        ),
        MigrateDestinationNode::getKeySchema(),
        'for_migration'
    );

// @todo Mapped fields
$this->addFieldMapping('body', 'content');
?>
```

When I try to access the migration UI page the count of items is correct, but I get and error when I try to load the task page to visualize the mappings and elements.

```
DOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Content ct LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0' at line 1: SELECT FROM {Content} ct LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0; Array ( ) in MigrateSourceSQL->fields() (line 211 of /Users/brightsitesSM/Sites/devdesktop/independentpoc-dev/docroot/sites/all/modules/migrate/plugins/sources/sql.inc).
```

Probably there is something missing in the code as the `SELECT` in the SQL query is empty.

Here are the screenshots of the migration page:
[image: Migration page]

... and the task page error:
[image: Task page]

Comment: The problem is that there are no fields in the SQL query (`SELECT FROM` is invalid SQL). Does that shed any light?

Comment: also the select is for `->select('Contenido', 'ct');` but your PDO error says `SELECT FROM Content` ... you need to check your table names and field names your using.

Comment: I think I had a similar issue with db_select. try to add `->fields('ct')` to your select.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's the issue I'll try adding fields to the db_select as @sareed sudgested. I think there is the issue.

Comment: @tenken sorry, that's a typo. The table name is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is the connection to the database. There aren't fields in the select.

```
SELECT FROM {Content} ct
```

To solve that one of the solutions is adding `->fields('ct');` to the database connection. This will select all the fields from the table ct:

```
SELECT ct.* FROM {Content} ct
```

Comment: Information about how fields function works [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Afields/7).